# How to call fragment from adapter class?

Tags: java, android

When I run the code bellow the following error is displayed:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference.

How to call fragment from adapter class?

```
Additem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
        Fragment fragment = null;
        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        if( position==0) {
            fragment = new AddtoCard_Fragment();
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            ft.replace(R.id.screenarea, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to do like "getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()" and before that check your getActivity() is null or not

Comment: i used public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.MyViewHolder> adapter so getActivity() not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Activity **Context** Using **Constructor** In **Adapter** Class then Use **ActivityContext.getSupportFragmentManager()**

I hope it's Help